# Typo3: remove Email attachment size limit

Tags: typo3, email-attachments

I have an contact form on the website with the possibility to add an attachment to the email. It's a normal form configured like this:

```
Position* | *Position=input
Name* | *Name=input
Vorname* | *Vorname=input
Firma | Firma=input
Strasse | Strasse=input
PLZ / Ort | PLZ_Ort=input
Land | Land=input
Telefon G | Telefon_G=input
Telefon P | Telefon_P=input
Mobile | Mobile=input
Email* | *Email=input
Website | Homepage=input
Ihre Nachricht | Ihre_Nachricht=textarea,,5
CV | attachment1=file, 4096000
 | formtype_mail=submit
 | html_enabled=hidden | 1
 | subject=hidden | Kontaktformular Internet
```

The problem now is, that the files aren't attached to the email, if they are bigger than 2MB. The upload doesn't have a problem, if I add 2 or more attachments, which are smaller than 2 MB. Also the `formmailMaxAttachmentSize` shouldn't be the problem, because it's set to 25000000.

I've searched for solutions on the internet but didn't find anything that would help me solve this issue.

The version of TYPO3 is 4.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the problem came up it really was because of the php.ini file, but it also didn't work after I changed the limit to 20M, because of a simple problem. Every time when I tested the formular I was logged in, in the backend. I don't know why, but if you use the preview feature it seems, that the formular doesn't work. So I simple had to log off from the backend and then test it again.

Answer (score 0):

Some operating systems (like Debian) come with a default upload size of 2 MB for PHP uploads.

Please check the configuration settings "upload_max_filesize" and "post_max_size" in the php.ini of your webserver.

Do both contain a value greater than 2 MB? If not, please set the limits to a value greater than 2 MB. The example below sets the upload limit to 10 MB.

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```